# if state.obj.val1 === true, return state.obj.val2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to find an object key value in a state array, and when that value is found (true) return the value of another key value in that object. I am really bad with loops :/ I've attempted  may variations of loops and this is only my latest attempt.

**the state**

```
this.state = {
      ids: [
        {
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: true,
        },
        {
          id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
          active: false,
        },
      ],
    };
```

**my latest attempt at retrieving the value** *returning `Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function`*

```
ifActiveField = this.ids.map((val) => {
    if (val["active"] === true) {
      return { ...val["id"] };
    }
  });
```

The `id` returned from the `active` object would then be passed to render a new component.

**This is what the page is returning when app is run**
[image: This is what the page is returning when app is run]

My full Code

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Embed, Icon, Image, List } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./Services.css";
import logo from "./images/EIB 3D Logo v25.png";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import MediaQuery from "react-responsive";

export default class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ids: [
        {
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: true,
        },
        {
          id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
          active: false,
        },
        {
          id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
          active: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  ifActiveField = this.ids.map((val) => {
    if (val["active"] === true) {
      return { ...val["id"] };
    }
  });
  changeActiveField = (id, active) => {
    this.setState({
      ids: this.state.ids.map((obj) =>
        obj.id === id ? { ...obj, active: false } : obj
      ),
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="serviceswrap">
        <div className="servicesbdrop">
          <div className="primarywrap">
            <div className="primaryvideo">
            <Embed
                autoplay={false}
                width='100px'
                height='100px'
                color="white"
                hd={false}
                id={this.ifActiveField}
                iframe={{
                  allowFullScreen: true,
                  style: {
                    padding: 10,
                  },
                }}
              />
              <div className="carousel">
                <div className="slider">
                  {this.state.ids.map((i) => (
                    <Image
                      className="carouselitem"
                      rounded
                      fluid
                      onClick={() => this.changeActiveField(i.id)}
                      src={
                        "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + i.id + "/hqdefault.jpg"
                      }
                      size="small"
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <List size="big" className="servicesList">
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">3D Printing</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Print your design using our 3d-printer.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">CNC Machining</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Print your design using our CNC machienery.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">Personalised Designs</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Design your idea to suite your needs.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">Laser Etching</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Elegant designs etched onto wood.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
              <List.Item>
                <List.Icon size="big" name="cog" />
                <List.Content>
                  <List.Header as="a">Wood Working</List.Header>
                  <List.Description>
                    Build custom designed indoor and outdoor wooden signage.
                  </List.Description>
                </List.Content>
              </List.Item>
            </List>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT ______________________________________________**

For reference, the three images surrounded in salmon BG on the following link
https://test.ghostrez.net/ then click on the Services page

These will be made clickable so that when clicked. the corresponding `object` in `this.state.ids` is found and `this.state.ids.active` is set to `active:true`.

**Here is my current question**
I'm trying to scan the `state.ids.objects.active` for which `object` has the `active` value `true`. When this object is found that objects `id` value should be returned.

**Example**
the function should find this state array object, and return `iCBvfW08jlo`.

```
{
          id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
          active: true,
        },
```

so then I can pass that value into rendering the appropriate `<div className='primaryvideo'></div>`

```
          <Embed
                autoplay={false}
                width='100px'
                height='100px'
                color="white"
                hd={false}
                id={this.ifActiveField}
                iframe={{
                  allowFullScreen: true,
                  style: {
                    padding: 10,
                  },
                }}
              />
```

Comment: `this.state.ids.map` ??

Comment: Hey, I see you didn't quite grasp what `map` (and other array methods) should be used for, or how are they used. I recommend reading this article: https://javascript.info/array-methods

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and the desired output? Your current explanation doesn't quite clarify your issue or goal.

Comment: Could you explain what you want exactly? I saw your code and you didn't use ifActiveField variable!

Comment: @EldarB.  I have added more details at the bottom of the question. hopefully, that helps clarify things? I will also take a look at the suggested article.

Comment: @Mohsen007 I've added additional explanations to the bottom of the question with a link to where you can see what I have so far.  I hope that explains what I'm trying to achieve. I have added the `div primaryvideo` to the full page code so that you can see the placement intended.

Comment: Why is the `ifActiveField` outside the constructor & every method ? 
`ids` is part of the state, it should be referred to as `this.state.ids`. Also I think you are trying to do a `filter` with `map`. `map` should be used when transform an array into another array of **same length**. `filter` should be used when you want to return an array with only some elements, based on a predicate (condition). `filter` returns an array of **lesser length**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, do you just want the first id that is "active"? Or an array of "active" ids?

If it is just the first then simply loop over them, and return the correct id if  active is true.

```js
var state = {
  ids: [{
      id: "iCBvfW08jlo",
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: "qvOcCQXZVg0",
      active: false,
    },
    {
      id: "YXNC3GKmjgk",
      active: false,
    },
  ]
};

function firstActiveId(ids) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (ids[i].active) {
      return ids[i].id;
    }
  }
}

console.log(firstActiveId(state.ids));
```

To use the function in your example simply call it passing in the array of ids. e.g.

```
ifActiveField = firstActiveId(this.ids);
```

If you want to use `find` or some such that is also possible...simply

```
ifActiveField = this.ids.find(x => x.active).id;
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you have something similar to a multiple choice question, where only one answer can be chosen, and you want to detect which one is currently selected.
Now, there's a basic solution using the [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, but it seems you are not very familiar with array methods, so I'll show the solution and explain what happens.

```
const conditionFunction = (id) => id.active;
const active = ids.find(conditionLambda);
```

The `find` method takes one parameter - a function. Then, it iterates through an array and calls that function with the current element, current index for every element in the array. It returns the first element for which the passed function returns `true`.

In simpler words, if we take your array, `find` goes through every single element in `ids` and calls `conditionLambda` like that: `conditionFunction(currentId, currentIndex)`:

```
conditionLambda({ id: "iCBvfW08jlo", active: true }, 0); // The first element in the array
conditionLambda({ id: "qvOcCQXZVg0", active: false }, 1); // The second element in the array
```

and so on.

`find` returns the first element for which `conditionLambda` returns `true`. So, in our case, the first element where `id.active` is truthy. That's the first element, so it returns `{ id: "iCBvfW08jlo", active: true }`.

Comment: "When this object is found that objects id value should be returned." - this returns an object not an "id value" (a string).

Comment: Can you edit it please? I don't seem to understand your comment, nor find what it is referring to

Comment: It was in the original question when you answered it..."When this object is found that objects id value should be returned." - your answer returns an object when the question asks for the string id. In the edit it now states: Example the function should find this state array object, and return iCBvfW08jlo.

Comment: Well then simply add `.id` at the end of the result..

Comment: My point is that - your solution doesn't answer the original question or the edited version of it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you look for an array of objects with active `true` , like this:

```js
const array = [
        {
            id: 1,
            active: true,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            active: true,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            active: false,
        },
    ];

    const filteredArray = array.filter((item) => item.active === true);

    console.log('filteredArray', filteredArray);
```

Comment: "When this object is found that objects id value should be returned" - I think they just want the single `id` not an array of matching objects.